# Get the latest live broadcasting You-Tube video id from channel

Tags: php, youtube-api, live-streaming

I want get the latest live you-tube video from you-tube channel. I tried following you-tube API

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=xxxxx&channelId=xxxxxx&part=id&order=date&maxResults=1&type=video&eventtype=live

I am getting the latest live steamed video ID after very big delay or sometime after stopping live broadcast only

could you please help me on my issue?

Thanks

Comment: Try using [LiveBroadcasts: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list), this will return a list of YouTube broadcasts that match the API request parameters. I'm not sure why it is behaving like that but you can also try reporting an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=0),if you think it is not working as intended. Hope this helps